# Printing webpage and styles are messed up

Tags: css, printing, styles

When I try to print something off of a website the styling becomes messed up. I am including two pictures for reference. Anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

This is what the page looks like and how I'd like it to look when I print:
[image: image1]

This is the print preview, and it also prints this way:
[image: image2]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In my experience, print style sheets are somewhat challenging. There are numerous cross-browser issues. (Mostly with IE). Generally I recommend a separate server call and open the content you want to print in a new window.

Comment: Define 'messed up'. How do you want it to look?

Comment: I'd like it to look as it does on the page. Messed up would be anything other than that.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the CSS is in a stylesheet that is `media="screen"`. That's likely the primary source of the formatting difference. That said, it's a Joomla site - try using that print icon in the upper right of the page. It will kick out a different page that is more printer friendly.

Comment: This also prints it as it looks for the print preview.

Comment: When you use the print icon on the page it looks the same? I see you're using Chrome. I tested it with Chrome and the page is formatted much differently - no header or footer.

To get it to look like it does on the page, the media="screen" needs to be removed. Are you a dev on this site?

Comment: Yeah, I inherited the job (I'm an intern) and I'm a bit confused at how to get rid of the media=screen thing. Since it's a joomla based site I can't just manually edit it out right?

Comment: I can't figure out where that is dynamically created at. I've done a ton of googling to no avail :(